# Aid with quick sort algorithm in java (netbeans)

Tags: java

I am quite new to programming and I am just starting using java. My task was to write a program using quick sort, I managed to write it but it always gives me an index out of bounds. Could anyone take a look at my code and help me by identifying what I am doing wrong? Thanks

This is the code for the main class.

```
package quicksort;

public class Quicksort {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    int[] x = {5,3,10,1,9,8,7,4,2,6,0};

    quicksort_class q = new quicksort_class(x);

    q.sort();

    for(int i = 0; i < 11-1; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(x[i]);
    }
   }
 }
```

This is the code for quicksort_class.

```
public class quicksort_class {

int[] array1 = new int[11];


public quicksort_class(int[] w)
{
    array1 = w;
}
public void partitionstep(int leftlimit, int rightlimit)
{   
    int LPointer = leftlimit;

    int RPointer = rightlimit;

    Random random = new Random();

    int midpoint = random.nextInt(11);

    int checknumber =  array1[midpoint];

    while(LPointer < RPointer)
    {
        while(array1[LPointer] <= checknumber)
        {
            LPointer = LPointer + 1;
        }

        while(array1[RPointer] >= checknumber)  
        {
            RPointer = RPointer --;
        }

     swap(LPointer, RPointer);

     partitionstep(leftlimit, midpoint - 1);

     partitionstep(midpoint + 1, rightlimit);
    }
}

public void swap(int x, int y)
{
int temp = array1[x];

array1[x] = array1[y];

array1[y] = temp;
}

public void sort()
{
partitionstep(0, array1.length - 1);
}
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting an index out of range exception? Please print the actual error message.

Comment: Can't the randomization of midpoint going to give you a point outside of the boundaries?

Comment: @Khanser It shouldn't because its staying within the bounds of the array. nextInt(11) will return a random value from [0 - 11). The array will always be size 11. As they partition, however, they should be adjusting the range that they're looking at (getting smaller than 11).

Comment: @bblincoe I meant outside of the boundaries of leftLimit and rightLimit.

Comment: General question: In your main, why are you looping for `11-1`? Why not simply loop until `x.length`?

Comment: @Khanser Then I agree. Still unsure of what is causing the exception, but the OP hasn't enlightened us yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `midpoint` value should be calculated based on your `leftLimit` and `rightLimit`. It should not be a random value based off of the fixed value `11`.

Comment: Correct, updated wording. I believe they need to base their random value on the current size of the limited array (based on left and right limit). They are partitioning the array after all.